# Why is my linked list only printing one value?

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I created a linked list but it's only printing the first value "1" and not the rest. I have an insert function to insert new nodes and then a show function to print out the node values but it's only printing the first value.

```
struct Node {
    int n;
    Node *next;

};

class LinkedList {
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
    
    public:
        LinkedList() {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }
        ~LinkedList(){};

        void insert_node(int value) {
            Node *new_node = new Node();
            new_node->n = value;
            new_node->next = NULL;

            if (head == NULL) {
                head = new_node;
                tail = new_node;
            }
            else {
                tail = new_node;
                tail->next = new_node;
            }
        }

        void show() {
            Node *new_node;
            new_node = head;

            while (new_node != NULL) {
                cout << new_node->n << endl;
                new_node = new_node->next;
            }
        }

};

int main() {

    LinkedList L;

    L.insert_node(1);
    L.insert_node(2);
    L.insert_node(4);
    L.insert_node(8);
    L.show();

}
```

Comment: *and not the rest* -- Then I suggest you insert just two values, and use the debugger to see why your `show` function does not print the second value.  If it doesn't work for two values, it certainly won't work for four values.  In addition, just seeing what happens with two values makes the issue much easier to debug.

Comment: When you add a new node to a list that has a head, where to you connect the previous node to the new node?

Comment: Note: The more we have to change in order to get your example code working the higher the risk we'll insert new bugs and write answers solving them or accidentally fix the bug and write no answers. Make sure your example compiles and preferably is a [mre].

Comment: [Fix the errors here](https://godbolt.org/z/zEcf7WYP6).  That's the code you posted.

Comment: One good trick when working on linked data structures is to draw the suckers. Draw the list before. Draw all the steps you need in order to perform an operation. Draw the list after. Then step through the code with the debugger that came with your tools and, doing exactly what the debugger shows you, try to draw the same pictures. When you can't you'll see the difference between what you should have and what you got and the solution's usually pretty easy.

Comment: @OP Also, and again, debug the most minimal example you can.  As I mentioned, the issue could have been seen with inserting just two elements.  Then you have an idea that the insertion must be wrong, and not simply the `show` function, since you only tried two elements and things were not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines

```cpp
                tail = new_node;
                tail->next = new_node;
```

means

```cpp
                new_node->next = new_node;
                tail = new_node;
```

Therefore, no link from `head` to `new_node` is created.

The lines should be:

```cpp
                tail->next = new_node;
                tail = new_node;
```

to first create link to the new node, and then update the tail pointer.